# Cucumber tests pass individually but fail together

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I'm having major issues running Cucumber tests from a feature together. No matter what I do I can run 1 or 2 scenarios together from a feature. After the first (or second) scenario runs the subsequent scenarios all fail, usually returning some type of "unable to locate resource X" error.

I'm using Selenium + Java to write the code for each individual method. As for browsers, I use Chrome.

```
@Scenario6
Scenario: Search for an item using the search functionality
Given Navigate to "Amazon.com" home page.
When Search for "iphone 7"
Then The search results return the desired items
@Scenario7   
Scenario: Select a department
Given Navigate to "Amazon.com" home page.
When Hover over the Departments dropdown menu
And Select Books&Audible category
And From the flyout menu select Books
Then Your "Amazon.com: Books" page is displayed
@Scenario8  
Scenario: Browse "New for you" items
Given Navigate to "Amazon.com" home page.
When Go to "Amazon basics" and click on "Home"
Then Your "Amazon.com: Home & Kitchen" page is displayed
```

As you can see all of these are extremely basic and don't involve session IDs, separate logins, user accounts or any type of security checks.

I've tried everything from deleting the tags, rewriting the individual methods to allow more time for Selenium to wait on elements to be visible, etc. I even added sleep timers to methods to ensure elements are visible.

I also looked over a number of topics related to this but, from what I read, they're all related to scenarios that have dependencies. My scenarios seem to be completely independent one from another. On top of that I close the browser every time after I complete a test.

If anyone has any idea how to fix this I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please combine the following 3 stories into single story and try. Because hover over the menu and sub menus and click steps should be in single steps.

```
When Hover over the Departments dropdown menu
And Select Books&Audible category
And From the flyout menu select Books
```

you can write with single story as

```
When I select Books from the category Books&Audible under Departments dropdown
```

It may works.